# is long polling in aws s3 available?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a node.js backend that sends out images to a secondary api for transformations and then those images appear in s3 bucket. The problem is that the secondary api doesn't inform my api when the file is created in the bucket.

Is there some sort of long polling in s3 available because spamming get requests doesn't feel right (also will get expensive).

I'm considering adding a trigger on new files in s3, that will invoke a lambda that will put a message into some sort of pub/sub message broker and then I could just subscribe to it but this seems a bit too complicated?

Comment: You can get your S3 object create notification directly into a SQS and your node.js application can listen to the sqs. No need to have a lambda.

Comment: No. There is no concept of "Long Polling" in Amazon S3.

Answer (score 0):

From the [S3 notification docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-overview) you can be notified via:

1. Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) topic
2. Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS) queue
3. AWS Lambda

The relative benefits or each one are up to you but don't poll S3 for changes.  Use one of these to be notified of the changes.  You can decide to get notices for just new objects or deleted object.